# Scripting, with split

Tags: linux, scripting, split

How can I write a shell script that will split only PDF files in my directory that are larger than 1,000KB?
 **Without using pdftk or any other downloadable tools**

I wish to split the PDF by Bytes, as too why I’m against using downloadable tools is because the people I work have made it clear we aren’t allowed to download any kind of tools.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is this to help with logs, for instance?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please clarify what it is exactly that you're trying to do?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: @Jules I agree, but https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/teaching-how-to-fish-considered-abusive

Comment: @Kusalananda I understand what you mean, and normally I'd agree -- though this is also a case of the question being too broad to even effectively comment on with a follow-up (does the OP want a shell script, a Perl script, Python?).

Comment: How do you want to split these PDF files? By bytes? Characters? Lines of PDF code? Typeset pages? If you want to process PDF files as PDF data, why are you so set against using a tool that understands the format?

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir split-files
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +10000000c -exec split -b 10000000 {} split-files/{}. ';'
```

This will find files in the current directory whose size exceeds 10000000 bytes (1000 KB). It will split these files so that each part is 1000 KB or less.  The splitting happens on byte boundaries.

The split files will be saved in the new directory `split-files` and will have the same name as the original files with a two letter suffix.

The original files are left untouched.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will find every file which is larger than 1000KB in the current directory (`.`):

```
find . -type f -size +1000k
```

You can `|` the results to `xargs` and execute your command on every file
e.g. for listing every file which is larger than `1000KB`:

```
find . -type f -size +1000k | xargs ls -l
```

In order to execute your `split` command you should replace the `ls -ls` in the above command which your `split` command.

Answer (score 0):

Use split command to split it in parts.
This creates parts with your choosen size from the source file:

```
split --bytes=1000K MyBigFile.jpg filepart
```

The parts become a random name that begins with your given name:

The files look something like:

```
filepartazza
filepartczaa
filepartqqzs
```

you can put it together easyly with:

```
cat filepart* >NewBigPicture.png
```

I wrote a whole script, that searches all files in a directory and splits them in a subdirectory.

Parameters for the script: "Folder where the files are" "size to match in K" "name of subdirectory and parts"

call it like: `./script.sh "/media/exchange/" "1000" "Parts"`

```
#!/bin/bash

SplitFiles() {

    File=""
    PartFolder=""
    IFS=$'\n'

        for File in `ls -lh --block-size=K $Folder | grep -v /`
        do
            Filename=$(echo $File | awk '{ print $1="";$2="";$3="";$4="";$5="";$6="";$7="";$8=""; print $0 }')
            Filename=$(echo $Filename | awk '{$1=$1};1')
            Filezise=$(echo $File | awk '{ print $5 }' | tr -d K)

            if [[ -z "$Filezise" || "$Filezise" -lt "$MatchSize" ]]; then
                :
            else
                PartFolder="$Folder""$Partname""Folder"
                mkdir -p "$PartFolder"
                split --bytes=1000K $Folder$Filename $PartFolder/$Partname                                                      
            fi
        done    
}

Folder="$1"
MatchSize="$2"
Partname="$3"

SplitFiles "$Folder" "$MatchSize" "$Partname"
```

it will create a subdirectory `/media/exchange/Parts` and store all parts inside.